# Resolved: Wordpress API Post request not updating

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm tring to write a WordPress post request (API) and although it reports a success message, the data is not updated. I temporarily created two extra columns in the WordPress user table (yes, not best practice). But the data is not saved. The jwt-auth plugin is used.

Current rest route:

```
register_rest_route( 'jwt-auth/v1', 'base_coords_post', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'base_coords_post',
));
```

And the callback

```
function base_coords_post() {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $userId = get_current_user_id();
    
    $data = array(
        'lat' => $_POST['lat'],
        'lng' => $_POST['lng']
    );
    $data_where = array(
        'ID' => $userId
    );
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->users , $data, $data_where);
}
```

How is it that the columns are not being updated? I checked the post values, they exist, the userID also exists.

**EDIT**
The fix was i tried to add varchar longer than the database field can hold. Changing the DB fixed the issue.

Comment: adding a answer to your own question with detailed explanation about the solution might help others who land on your question in future

Comment: Already did at the bottom